# multi touching in QML

Tags: qml

I am new at QML. And I am trying to develop a piano consisting of white and black buttons. But I could not do multi touching to the buttons of the piano just like playing the real piano by using many fingers. How can I do this? Can you please help me in this subject?

I am waiting your answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Multitouch is not officially supported right now, but there is some code in qt-labs. 
Have a look at https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-11638?focusedCommentId=137178&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-137178

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this: http://blogs.forum.nokia.com/blog/lauri-jaaskelas-forum-nokia-blog/2011/02/03/raw-multitouch-pointer-events-in-qml

Update: this is even better: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/08/a-toucharea-for-qml/

Answer (score 1):

For future askers:
Use QT5.

There is introduced [MultiPointTouchArea](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html) which can handle more than one touch point.

Comment: Updated [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-multipointtoucharea.html).